# $m(\{x\in K^c;d(x, K) < \varepsilon\}) \leq C\varepsilon$

Tags: functions, lebesgue-measure

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a nonempty compact set, and

$f(\varepsilon)= m(\{x\in K^c;d(x, K) < \varepsilon\})$, where

$m$ is the Lebesgue measure, and $\displaystyle d(x, K)=\inf_{y\in K}|x-y|$.

Does the following hold?

There is a $\delta>0, C>0$ such that $f(\varepsilon)\leq C\varepsilon$ for all $0<\varepsilon<\delta$.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the stated property does not hold.

Consider, for example, the set
$$
K := \{0\} \cup \left\{\frac{1}{n}:\ n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\right\}.
$$
For a fixed (small) $\varepsilon > 0$, you have that
$$
\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} > 2\varepsilon
\qquad
\forall n \leq N_\varepsilon,
$$
with $N_\varepsilon$ an integer of the order $1/\sqrt{2\varepsilon}$.

Hence
$$
f(\varepsilon) \geq m\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{N_\varepsilon} B_\varepsilon(1/n)\right)
= 2\varepsilon N_\varepsilon \sim \sqrt{2\varepsilon}.
$$